# Rendering a Vue app in Shadow DOM using Custom Element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

So I have a full featured (Routing etc) Vue 3 app that I need to embed on random page somewhere, but I don't want to use an iframe for various reasons so I'm looking to achieve this using Shadow DOM and Custom Element.

The way I thought it would work:

- ✅ Build the Vue App
- ✅ Publish the `dist` folder
- ✅ Create a Custom Element
- ✅ Create Shadow DOM in the `constructor`
- ✅ Load `dist/index.html`
- ❌ Vue App renders in Shadow DOM

... except it doesn't. Everything technically works but the Vue app doesn't render at all.

[image]

What am I missing?

My attempt: https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-7trm5i?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.html

***Edited to add:***

- Same result even if I deploy the app to a [service like Vercel](https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/) and use it as `src`.

Comment: I presume you have read: https://www.robpeck.com/2020/04/using-vue-single-file-components-inside-shadow-dom/#:~:text=And%2C%20yes%2C%20Vue%20can%20totally,a%20bit%20of%20setup%20work.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes I have, and its the first part — mounting Vue app in shadow root. I then also need to wrap it in a custom element to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a right way to do it. You are using fetch to get the HTML page. The HTML page has following script and style tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="bumblebee">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vue Cart</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.0f5a3d92.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.ab0eb239.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.8fd7686d.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="app"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Look at this script: `<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.0f5a3d92.js">`.

When this tag is added via `innerHTML`, the browser will try to find the `index.0f5a3d92.js` file using the domain from which you are serving the main page. It is not asking the domain from where you are getting this HTML. Ideally, it should be this:

https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/index.0f5a3d92.js

But it is making call to this:

https://stackblitz.com/assets/index.0f5a3d92.js

You will have to rewrite the `src` attribute before you add it to HTML.

On a side note, this is an anti-pattern on what you are trying to do. Web component is not a real substitute for `iFrame`. Plus, a page should have only one top level `head` tag. You are introducing multiple head and body tags here. Browser will **silently** handle it but it is still anti-pattern.

The right way to do this is to bundle your Vue application with custom element definition. Then upload this bundled script to some CDN. From there, add it as a script on the page and the element should render when browser encounters the custom element.

Comment: Sorry, should've said I also tried fixing the asset path: https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-7trm5i?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.html

Comment: `bundle your Vue application with custom element definition` Do you mean bundle the entire app in a single but huge JS file? Vue is still required either in the bundle or external, right?

Comment: @eozzy, Currently you have two things separate - your Vue.js code and the Web component wrapper you are writing around it. They should be together. Refer to this [guide for more information](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue).

Comment: @eozzy Greetings, I hope everything is going well. We are trying to do the same but we have not achieved results. We want to embed a Vue App in a custom component. We use Fetch to get the HTML content and then do the InnerHTML but the #app div remains empty, it's very similar to your case. 

Do you have any ideas that can help us?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple html, body, head tags in single document, so the html parser ignores the html, head and body tags of the Vue app.

Before:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="bumblebee">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue Cart</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/index.0f5a3d92.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/vendor.ab0eb239.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/index.8fd7686d.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

After parsing:

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue Cart</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/index.0f5a3d92.js"></script>
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/vendor.ab0eb239.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://vue-cart-ayoc0w7nv-eozzy.vercel.app/assets/index.8fd7686d.css">
    <div id="app"></div>
```

So ultimately the html structure changes from the original one which Vue Virtual DOM can not work with.

So I don't think you can use Shadow DOM like an iframe.